# AutoValue how to call super

Tags: auto-value

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class MyError extends Throwable {

    public static MyError create(
            Throwable ex,
            MyErrorCode errorCode) {
        return new AutoValue_MyError(ex, errorCode);
    }

    public abstract Throwable getError();

    public abstract MyErrorCode myErrorCode();
}
```

I use `AutoValue` to create `MyError` class and question is how do I do `super(ex.getCause())` to pass the actual context. Looks like the generated implementation doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAS-A relation is better than IS-A relation. So MyError class should not extend Throwable class.

I think we can't call `super(ex.getCause())`.

AutoValue creates immutable object using Builder pattern.
See the issue on [Github auto repository](https://github.com/google/auto/issues/277)
    `getError()` method will return `Throwable` object and then you can call `getClause()` method on the same.